# Javascript HTML values to Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$("#keyword-content").html()`

Produces

```
  <p>
    javascript
  </p>
  <p>
    ruby
  </p>
  <p>
    python
  </p>
```

How can I convert this to `["javascript", "ruby", python"]` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `map` method:

```
var arr = $('#keyword-content p').map(function(){
      return $(this).text()
}).get()
```

Comment: Thanks @undefined, this is a very clean pattern. Waiting to accept

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var myArray = [];

$("#keyword-content p").each(function(index,item) {
    myArray.push($(item).text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt but this throws an error `#<HTMLParagraphElement> has no method 'text'`. I tried something similar with underscore.js before I came to SO for help.